# Angular2 Router v3, navigate to different level: TypeError: Cannot read property '_routeConfig' of null

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm using new Router v3.0.0-alpha.3. Imagine my routes looks like:

```
                              App
                              /\
                             /  \
                       Settings  Main
                          / \        
                         /   \      
                       User  Account
```

From the view of User component I would like to navigate to Main component. If I navigate to any component within the Settings level it works fine, but when I try to navigate to other level I get an error:

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property '_routeConfig' of null
```

I naviagate using routerLink directive:

```
[routerLink]="['/main']"           <- doesn't work
[routerLink]="['/settings']"       <- works
[routerLink]="['/settings/user']"  <- works
```

This seems like a global issue. I can only navigate within this same level. Any Idea how I can bypass it?

My routes passed to bootstrap:

```
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
    ...MainRoutes,
    ...SettingsRoutes
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
    provideRouter(routes)
];
```

**main.routes.ts:**

```
export const MainRoutes: RouterConfig = [{
    path: '/main',
    component: SettingsComponent
}];
```

**settings.routes.ts:**

```
export const SettingsRoutes: RouterConfig = [{
    path: '/settings',
    component: SettingsComponent,
    children: [{
        path: '/user',
        component: UserSettingsComponent,
        index: true
    }]
}];
```

**Edit:**

As given link in comments doesn't work anymore I will suggest the temporary fix. The bug still exists in alpha.7 version of router but is going to be fixed [here](https://github.com/angular/vladivostok/commit/9d6819b39e2b7952bc724c7531c4f53182af5e95)

The problem is in **router.js** file, function **GuardChecks.prototype.runCanDeactivate** line 309 (in router v.alpha.7):

```
var canDeactivate = curr._routeConfig ? curr._routeConfig.canDeactivate : null;
```

change it to:

```
var canDeactivate = curr && curr._routeConfig ? curr._routeConfig.canDeactivate : null;
```

Please remember that this should be treated as temporary fix, not suitable for automated production environment!

Comment: Seems to be https://github.com/angular/vladivostok/issues/48

Comment: Have you tried Angular2 RC.3?

Comment: As a matter of fact I did after your comment but this will not change anything as the problem is in router that has not got new release yet: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/router

Comment: In the current version alpha.7  there should be no leading  `/` in routes.

Comment: also index doesn't exist any more .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: fixed in `alpha.8`

---

Until a new `@angular/router` is released, you'll want to update the source code manually as discussed here:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9480#issuecomment-227845866

Comment: Currently alpha.8 is released and this bug is fixed :)